# Write Form Field From MikTex (via Pandoc) which iTextSharp Can Parse

Tags: itext, latex, pandoc, miktex

I'm doing some tests with `iTextSharp` to see it would work to automate a workflow I have. So, I am using `Pandoc` to generate some `pdf`s from `markdown`. But when I generate the files `iTextSharp` doesn't recognize the fields I have generated. It recognizes the fields in a different `pdf` I didn't create so I figure it is something that I am doing wrong.

**Solution**:

I guess I needed the form wrapper around it:

```
\begin{Form}

My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}

\end{Form}
```

---

So, I start with this code in `Test.md`:

```
My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}
```

If I use this command `pandoc -s .\Test.md -o Test.tex` to generate the `tex` file I get this result:

```
... see pre code below if this part of the latex file matter to you

\begin{document}

My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}

\end{document}
```

Of course, I use this command `pandoc -s .\Test.md -o Test.pdf` to actually generate the `pdf`. Should I be using a different command to generate the `TextField`?

Code generated in `tex` file not included above for brevity:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode=true}{hyperref} % options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provides euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother


\date{}
```

Comment: Please share one such sample pdf.

Comment: I already figured out the problem as stated in the question: I needed to add `\begin{Form}...\end{Form}` wrapper.

Comment: If that indeed is the solution to your issue, please create an actual answer to your question, put the solution there, and eventually accept the answer. In its current state your question looks as if some aspect still is unsolved.

Comment: Good point. Will do! For some reason I was thinking there was a time limit on how quickly you can answer your own question. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I guess I needed the form wrapper around it:

```
\begin{Form}

My field: \underline{\TextField[name=AField]{}}

\end{Form}
```